# Server 2008r2 x64 and ODBC Connector

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, windows-server-2008-r2

server 2008r2 x64,
mysql 5.5.24 x86,
access 2007 x86

im trying to connect mysql backend to access 2007 frontend...

after I installed  mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi and rebooted server. that driver will not show up in the drivers tab of ODBC Datasource administrator.or in the list of drivers if i try to add a new driver

also installed mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.5-win32.msi also just to try newer version, that does not show up either. repaired both install, rebooted, reinstalled, same thing. all i see is a mysql driver...

any ideas whats going on?

**UPDATE:**

Used C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe and same results.. no driver there...

really not sure whats going on... any special dependancies required? not sure what i could be missing.. as i said, neither driver is visible, yet both installed without error (to my knowledge, are there install logs???)

default path for both drivers during installation was c:\programs Files (x86)\MySQL\connector ODBC 5.1\ or c:\rograms Files (x86)\MySQL\connector ODBC 5.2\

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

After installing 32-bit ODBC components onto a 64-bit machine you need to run the ***32-bit*** ODBC Administrator, normally found at

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

If you just go the normal `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC)` route then you will be looking at the *64-bit* environment, and your *32-bit* options will not be visible.

Comment: Weird, opened the C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe and same results.. no driver there...

really not sure whats going on... any special dependancies required? not sure what i could be missing.. as i said, neither driver is visible, yet both installed without error (to my knowledge, are there install logs???)

default path for both drivers during installation was c:\programs Files (x86)\MySQL\connector ODBC 5.1\ or c:\rograms Files (x86)\MySQL\connector ODBC 5.2\

any thoughts?

Comment: @Ford I've never encountered a situation where special dependencies have prevented MySQL ODBC from installing correctly. I just tested an install of `mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.5-win32.msi` onto a plain vanilla Windows Server 2012 (x64) virtual machine (without even having MySQL Server on it) and the 32-bit ODBC drivers installed fine.

Comment: @Ford RE: Install logs - You could check the Windows Event Viewer under "Applications" for events from `MsiInstaller`. I found a message in there that said "Product: MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.2 32bit (community edition) -- Installation operation completed successfully."

Comment: ok, my event viewer shows success for 5.1 (event id 117070) and 5.2 (event id 1033)           i am running a wamp server if it matters any..